# Simple CAS server in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm working on a PHP website which use a CAS (Central Authentication Service) authentication to identify user. I have imported the website on my computer which is not recognized by the CAS server.

Is there a simple CAS server that I can install on my computer (Linux (Ubuntu)) in order to use it during the development (I can change the URL of the CAS server for the development environment)? It would be perfect if the CAS server was simple and didn't require any dependencies. As long as it can send a token to my website it's ok.